# gcc vector extensions don't work as stated in docs

Tags: gcc, sse, vectorization

As per [Using vector instructions through built-in functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html), this program should compile:

```
int main(){
    double v_sse __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

    /*
     * Should work: "For the convenience in C it is allowed to use a binary vector operation where one operand is a scalar."
     */
    v_sse=v_sse+3.4;

    /*
     * Should work: "Vectors can be subscripted as if the vector were an array with the same number of elements and base type."
     */
    double result=v_sse[0];
}
```

Instead I get errors at both operations, complaining about invalid operand/types.

I compile on a x86-64 system, so -msse2 is implicit, and my compiler is 4.6.3 (tested also with 4.7.0, it doesn't work). Where's the catch?

Comment: Did you use the C++ compiler?

Comment: @drhirsch yes. Are those extensions strictly for gcc?

Comment: I don't know, but it was worth a guess ;-)

Comment: @drhirsch gcc accepts the subscript, but it still rejects the +

Comment: You should ask at gcc-help here: http://gcc.gnu.org/lists.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ refers to current development.

Look at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-X.Y.Z/ to find the documentation for the version you're using (see the index at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/ for links to the docs for the most recent point release of each series).

In this case:

- the binary operator functionality is not documented for [4.6.3](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.3/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html) - because it was introduced as a new feature in 4.7: see the [4.7 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/changes.html);
- the subscript feature *is* present in 4.6.3; and
- both features are specifically documented as working "in C"

...which explains what you're seeing.

Both of these do work with 4.7.0 when compiling as C -- but not when compiling as C++.